# How to inheritance functions from a base js file in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I moved from automation framework development with java to protractor & javascript so this is new to me. In my protractor framework I need to create a base screen js file with global functions that can be called from other screens js files. See the following example. How to make login.js inheritance all functions from base.js so the test in loginTest.js will work when calling base.js functions directly from login.js?

**base.js**

```
var base= function(){

    var that = {
        navigateToLogin: function(url){
        browser.get(url);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return require('login.js');
        },

        click: function(element, page){
            element.click();
            console.log('LOG: Clicked on element ' + element);
            return that || page;
        },

         insert: function(element, text){
            element.clear().then(function() {
                element.sendKeys(text);
                console.log('LOG: Insert text: ' +text);
            });
            return that;
        },
    };
    return that;
};
module.exports = new base();
```

**login.js**

```
var login = function(){

    var that = {

        func1: function() {
         // do something
                        return that 
        },

        func2: function() {
           // do something

                       return that;
        },
            };
    return that;
};
module.exports = new login();
```

**loginTests.js**

```
describe('Login tests - ', function() {

    var loginPage = require('login.js');

       describe('Success login: ', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            loginPage.navigateToLogin(“http://login.url”);
                   });

        it("Success login as admin",function(){
           loginPage.insert(“element(by.name("username"))”,”admin@mail”l)
                           .insert(“element(by.name("password"))”,”12345”)                             
                       .click(“element(by.name("loginButton"))”,“home.js”);
                  });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node.js > 4 (5 and more) try to use ES6 classes -

**basepage.js:**

```
class BasePage {
    constructor() {

    }

    open() {
        browser.get(url);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
exports = BasePage
```

**loginpage.js:**

```
class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    login(username, password) {
        //do your login stuff here
    }
}

exports = LoginPage
```

Then in your test:

```
let LoginPage = require('loginpage.js');
describe('Login tests - ', function () {
    let loginPage = new LoginPage()  

    beforeEach(function () {
        loginPage.open('/login')
    })

    it("Success login as admin", function () {
        loginPage.login('admin', '123456')
    })
})
```

Comment: Update to latest version (i think it is 8.0.0 now)